# Using python to calculate 3d points in a plane from a 2D image, having some known locations on the 2D image (homography?)

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, 2d, coordinates

I'm needing to solve a problem where I have a plane in known 3D space (a court), and I know the coordinates of its corners (and other line intersections). I then have a 2D image of the court that I can digitise to find the pixel coordinates.

I understand that I can relate the two via homography (and have successfully done this in MATLAB), and calculate new 3D points based on an (x,y) location in the 2D image. The 3D z-coordinate is always 0.

My question is how can I perform this in Python?

court_coordinates

```
array([[-3.05 , -6.705,  0.   ],
       [ 3.05 , -6.705,  0.   ],
       [-3.05 ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [ 3.05 ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
       [-3.05 ,  6.705,  0.   ],
       [ 3.05 ,  6.705,  0.   ]], dtype=float32)
```

pixel_coordinates

```
array([[ 257.4123305 ,  694.90208136],
       [1016.79422895,  694.90208136],
       [ 338.1439609 ,  505.68732261],
       [ 936.06259855,  510.73304951],
       [ 393.6469568 ,  397.20419426],
       [ 885.60532955,  402.24992116]])
```

New 2D point:
`[(635.8418479974771, 689.8563544623148)]`

This should give a 3D coordinate of `(0,-6.705,0)`

So far I have tried using cv2.findHomography, inputting my two sets of coordinates. Then I have used the inverse of this matrix, multiplied with the new pixel 2D coordinates, however this doesn't return a realistic 3D coordinate.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the formula, that you're using to perform the homographic tranlation? Knowing that formula it would be easy for me to express it in python. It should be nothing more than a matrix multiplication of your 2D vector (filled up with a zero to become a 3D vector) with the homographic matrix.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In Matlab I use my known 3D locations (first set of coordinates) and 2D pixel locations (second set) within the homography_solve function and then for any new pixel coordinates I use the homography_transform function.

Within Python I've used the cv2.findHomography function to calculate the homography matrix, and then the inverse of this matrix with new pixel coordinates. However the returned coordinate in 3D space is incorrect.